# Apache Redirect Permanent For URL with Data in String (Question Mark)

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, redirect, mod-alias

I am looking for an Apache redirect where the source URL has a question mark in it.

```
Redirect permanent /course/view.php?id=68 http://exmaple.com/page.php
```

I've tried escaping the question mark, but that doesn't work.
I've read a couple pages on the web about using Rewrite conditions, however it didn't quite make sense to me, or it was a little bit different than what I wanted to accomplish.

Comment: Have you tried puttin quotes around it? "/course/view.php?id=68"

Comment: I tried single quotes earlier, would double quotes make a difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the following to the `.htaccess` file in the root directory of your site.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase / 

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /course/view\.php\?id=68 [NC]  
RewriteRule ^ http://exmaple.com/page.php [L,R=301]
```

Comment: This works, however it carries the ?id=68 with it and appends to the destination URL

Comment: @BobbyS: Change last line to: `RewriteRule ^ http://exmaple.com/page.php? [L,R=301]`