# htaccess rewrite from Windows server to linux box

Tags: .htaccess

I have an old site URL like this:
http://www.test.com/partners/redirects.aspx?product=MobileDevice

Currently this URL redirects over to an external site, lets call it http://www.google.com.  This happens with some janky, old Admin Portal that was developed about 10 years ago.

This site lives in a windows environment.  We are moving away from windows and over to a Linux environment and php.

How can I carry this redirect over on the linux side?

I tried this:

```
Redirect 301 /partners/redirects\.aspx\?product\=MobileDevice http://www.google.com
```

and it didn't work.  I tried with the `.` `?` `=` escaped (with `\`) and not escaped.

Comment: Can you post some of your .htaccess file?

Comment: @IanOBrien Don't edit just formatting. This post still could use more modifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to escape anything. `Redirect 301 /partners/redirects.aspx?product=MobileDevice http://www.google.com` should work. But you stated that you attempted this.

I'm thinking your Apache instance doesn't allow processing of .htaccess files. Check your VirutalHost or global Apache configuration to see if `AllowOverride All` is declared somewhere. Without that, Apache will ignore most, if not all, directives in the .htaccess file.

**EDIT:**

Doing more research, here's another question of the exact same problem. [Apache Redirect Permanent For URL with Data in String (Question Mark)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9182585/apache-redirect-permanent-for-url-with-data-in-string-question-mark)

Seems like the query string is what isn't working for you. You may need to change this answer so it blindly redirects without carrying the query string along. So you would end up with something like

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase / 

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /partners/redirects.aspx\?product=MobileDevice [NC]  
RewriteRule ^ http://www.google.com [L,R=301]
```

Comment: You can test to see if Apache picks up the .htaccess file by causing a syntax error- just type `asdf` at the top of the file. Typically the first thing I do.

Comment: Vondruska, the only change I had to make to yours was adding "^[A-Z]{3,9}\" to the first line after the ^ and before the /partners.  I will mark yours as correct, if you could please edit your answer so we don't confuse anybody going forward!  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @cschneider27 Ah yep, edited the answer to reflect it! %{THE_REQUEST} translates to "GET /partners/redirects.aspx?product=MobileDevice HTTP/1.1" (per [Apache's documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)). The regular expression matches any captial letter in length from 3 to 9 characters. So it would cover all of the main HTTP verbs like GET, POST, PUSH, DELETE, OPTIONS, etc.